# Magento product save error transactions have not been committed

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.7

When I'm trying to save a product on a customers magento install using a script I get the following error after calling $product->save();

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back
```

For example...

```
        $_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('supplier')->AddAttributeToFilter('supplier', $options[$vendor['old_supplier_name']]);

    foreach($_products as $product){

        $product->setData('supplier', $options[$vendor['new_supplier_name']]);
        $product->save();

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from the fact that when getting a product collection not all attributes are loaded. Calling `save` on a product from a collection can cause big problems. You need to call `load` before saving.  Also products can be saved only from the admin store.

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID)); //set the admin store;
$_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('supplier')->AddAttributeToFilter('supplier', $options[$vendor['old_supplier_name']]);
foreach($_products as $product){
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
    $product->setData('supplier', $options[$vendor['new_supplier_name']]);
    $product->save();
}
```

**But don't use the code above** just to update one field. It's reaaaaaaly slow.
Use this instead:

```
$_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('supplier')->AddAttributeToFilter('supplier',  $options[$vendor['old_supplier_name']]);
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes($_products->getAllIds(), array('supplier'=>$options[$vendor['new_supplier_name']]), 0);
```

Now some explanations.
`updateAttributes` can be used to bulk update product attributes. It takes 3 parameters.

- an array of product ids to be updated
- an array with the attributes to be updated
- the store id. 0 means default values.

Comment: Thanks very much for the code above and your explanation! Very helpful.

Comment: Hi @Marius we have blocket with this issue https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293795/rolled-back-transaction-has-not-been-completed-correctly-while-saving-product can u help me on this please